# Horizontal footer from a stacked footer

Tags: html, css

I was wondering if anyone knew how to properly make a horizontal footer from a stacked one. Currently I have three rows one of social media icons, one of my name, and one that's a button. I want them in desktop to be in the same row and centered. If anyone could give me some advice that would really help! Thanks!

```js
<script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"
     integrity="sha256-7LkWEzqTdpEfELxcZZlS6wAx5Ff13zZ83lYO2/ujj7g="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>             
<script src="SlickNav-master/dist/jquery.slicknav.js"></script>  
            
<script>
 $(function(){
  $('#menu').slicknav();
 });
</script>
```

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 568px){
  #powered_by_storenvy {display: none !important;}
}

@media screen and (min-width: 568px){ 
#footer_info {display: none;}
}
  #footer_links {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  
  background: #1FA0A3;

  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1.6rem; 
    border-top: none;
    padding:20px; 
  
}

#footer_links ul {
   
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding-left: 0; 
}

#footer_links li {
    line-height: 24px;line-height: 2.4rem; 
    list-style: none;
    background-color: #1FA0A3;      /*: Footer background :*/
    margin-bottom: 5px;margin-bottom: .5rem;
}

#footer_links ul a {
  color:black;
  text-decoration: none; /*: Footer Links :*/;
  padding: 0 6px;
 padding: 0 .6rem;
   
}

#footer_links a:hover {
  color: #BBBBBB;                   /*: Footer Links Hover :*/
}

.footer-small {
    font-size: 12px;
  font-size: 1.2rem; 
}


.ghost-button {
    color: black;
   
    border: 1px solid #009688;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 7px 12px;
    font-weight: normal;
    margin: 6px 0;
 width:250px;
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Philosopher', sans-serif;
   
}

.ghost-button:hover, .ghost-button:active {
  color:#fff;
  background:#009688;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/a74e3d793f.js"></script>

<div id="footer_links">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="/contact"><i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
      <a href="/faq"><i class="fa fa-tumblr fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>

</a>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x " aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
      <a href="http://www.blogger.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x " aria-hidden="true"></i>
 </a>
    
    </li>
    <span class="footer-small"> MaKayla  &copy; 2017</span>
    
    
    <li>
    <a href="https://superdevresources.com/super-simple-ghost-button-css/" class="ghost-button" target="_blank">Resume</a> 
     
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't exactly understand what you're trying to do? The icons all seem to be in a row, did you want the other links to be in the same row?

Comment: I just want all of the content in one row so the social media icons on the left side of the row, my name in the middle, and the button on the far right @Braeden Orchard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a `@media` query and flexbox. This will do it, where 600px is the breakpoint where you want items to change.

```
@media (min-width:600px) {
  #footer_links ul {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked like a dream! Thank you so so much @Michael Coker

Comment: @Cakers sweet np!